# Why can I not connect my external hard drive to my Yureka phone?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, micromax-yu-yureka

When I connect my Lenovo external hard drive to my Yureka phone by the combination of OTG cable, Y cable, and the power bank, it shows the message that is connected and disconnected constantly.

Why can I not connect my external hard drive to my Yureka phone?

Comment: is the hard drive running on NTFS, FAT32? or another format?

Answer (score 0):

This trick you are trying to do does not depend upon any single condition. To connect an external hard drive to a phone with the help of USB-OTG requires satisfying both hardware and software compatibility.

- As you said 'when you tried to connect external hard drive it shows constantly connecting and disconnecting, this maybe be an issue of power needed to support external hard drive. I guess your device has a 5 V battery with a capacity of 2500 mAh. To mount a 1 TB device on that power puts a tremendous workload on Android devices. (There are devices like OnePlus or Nexus with bigger specifications that can do this job so it's definitely not an 'impossible' thing)
- In the case of software, your phone or phone's file system might not have compatibility with the file system of the external hard drive. Try to use different file explorers like ES File Explorer or there is an app available on Play Store named 'Paragon' that can mount NTFS, HFS+, and other file systems (requires root), and then check again.

Before writing this answer, I tried connecting my own Seagate backup+ 1TB  hard drive to my Xiaomi Redmi Note 3. It shows a notification 'Blank USB storage or unsupported file system'. My device has a 4000 mAh battery and notification is not fluctuating so I guess it's a software issue in case of me and a hardware issue in the case of you.